# Make layer on and off using checkboxes

Tags: leaflet

I have sample of layers stored on my database, I tried to display names of this layers in a panel, each layer is associated to a checkbox. When I check each checkbow I want to add its correspondent layer on map and remove it from map when checkbox is unchecked. My problem is I can't remove layers from map.
Here is my php and jquery snippet code:

**jquery file **

```js
$.get( $("#myForm5").attr("action"),
$("#myForm5 :input").serializeArray(),
function(data) {
 $("#Liste").html(data);
                      $('input[id^="DisplayCheckbox"]').on('change', function() 
{
 var CoordItem =  $(this).parents("div.parent").find("li#Lis  te").text();
 var content = $(this).val();
 var DataItem = $(this).parents("div.parent").find("li#ListeData").text();
var array = DataItem.split(',');

var dataDomaine = $.parseJSON(CoordItem);
var geojsonFeature = 
 {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
    "name": content,
     },
     "geometry": {
       "type": dataDomaine.type,
       "coordinates":dataDomaine.coordinates
     }
 };
 var layer = L.geoJson(geojsonFeature);
                    if($(this).is(":checked"))
 {
   layer.addTo(map);
   map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
 
 }else
 {    
                                              map.removeLayer(layer); 
                               
 
 });//end change checkbox

});//end get function
```

**php file**

```js
<?php
......
echo '<ul>'
echo '<div id="' . $row2['nom'] . '" class="col-sm-10 parent"><li class="Liste" id="idListe">' . $row2['nom'] . '</li>
<div class="checkbox DisplayLayer">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="id" id="DisplayCheckbox" value="' . $row2['nom'] . '"></label></div>
 <li id="ListeData" name="id" style="display:none;">' . $tostring. '</li>';
.......
echo '<li id="ListeGeom" name="id" style="display:none;">' . $row3[0]. '</li></div><br/>';

echo '</ul>
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are removing "new created" feature - there is no reference to existing layer.
Before *layer.addTo(map)* give a layer private property, e.g *layer._id = 1*. And in an else block, let's iterate over all layers and try to find it by id. Something like this:

```
map.eachLayer(function(layer){
    if(layer._id == 1) map.removeLayer(layer)
})
```

Comment: I will try that, Thank you @Sebastian Schulz

Comment: I faced an issue, I can't figure out how to create this id dynamically because layers are added to map dynamically when each checkbox is checked, I don't know how to change layer id for each layer. Can you help me please?

Comment: I still not found solution to my problem

Comment: Maybe take a look fo this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wmnjv78y/). It's an example of clear markers after click on them. Here you have a way to add markers to map with private properties and catching it.

Comment: I can clear layers after click on them but the problem is how to remove them using checkboxes.

Comment: Use the change event listener (or change method in jQuery), e.g https://jsfiddle.net/t42ejwqq/

Comment: Thank you @Sebastian Schulz, but I'm using dynamic data which came from database so this is my issue

Comment: I know, but you need to merge solutions. Use private property to identify feature, push it to array and write checking function for checkbox. If you need more information share a fiddle with output from server and your code.